# What determines how much partial reflection occurs at a boundary between two media?

Tags: optics, reflection, geometric-optics, fiber-optics, optical-materials

Some thoughts I had about this are:

- does it depends on the two media? Surely it must do. If so, what properties of the media dictate the extent of partial reflection?
- this point is highly dependent on the answer to the previous point, but is there a mathematical description possible for how much reflection occurs?
- Finally, does it depends on the angle of incidence? This is something I would very much like to investigate myself, but unfortunately I don't have the equipment for this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mathematical description you are looking for is called the [Fresnel equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_equations). Here is the most common form, for non-magnetic media:
$$
R_s = \frac{n_1\cos\theta_1 - n_2\cos\theta_2}{n_1\cos\theta_1 + n_2\cos\theta_2}
$$
$$
R_p = \frac{n_1\cos\theta_2 - n_2\cos\theta_1}{n_1\cos\theta_2 + n_2\cos\theta_1} 
$$
$R$ is the fraction of light reflected, for $s$ and $p$ polarizations. You can find the other forms of the equations in the linked Wikipedia article.

As you can see from the equations, partial reflection depends on the indices of refraction of both materials ($n_1$ and $n_2$) as well as the angle of incidence ($\theta_1$). You can see the angle of refraction ($\theta_2$) in there as well, but it itself can be calculated from the indices and the angle of incidence.